# Android: How to get file list from url

Tags: android, android-file

I want to list files from url. For example, there are some jpeg files inside http://www.example.com/jpegfile/ that i want to list these files on my android app.

I know how to list files inside the phone, but i dont know how to list from url.

thank!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, before you can list your files from URL, you need to download them. Check this link, it will help you properly download your images, then you'll have to just show them where you want.

[Multithreading for Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer!!!

But I don't want to download them before listing the files, Should I write a script or something for the web server???

The web server is set up by me.

Thank you!!!